# How to compare multiple nodes with XPath

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0

Given the XML below, I am trying to write a XPath which returns only this match:

```
<TOKEN BEGIN="17" END="19" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" PROP="C" DOUBLE="YES" />
```

This is the input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DOCUMENT>
  <SECTION>
    <PARAGRAPH TRACK="4">
      <SENTENCE NAME="PRIMARY" COUNT="4">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="9" END="11" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" />
        <TOKEN BEGIN="32" END="37" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" />
        <TOKEN BEGIN="167" END="169" SENTENCE_BEGIN="158" SENTENCE_END="316" />
        <TOKEN BEGIN="210" END="215" SENTENCE_BEGIN="158" SENTENCE_END="316" />
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="2">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="139" END="141" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" PROP="A" DOUBLE="YES" />
        <TOKEN BEGIN="143" END="145" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" PROP="B" />
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="17" END="19" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" PROP="C" DOUBLE="YES" />
      </SENTENCE>
    </PARAGRAPH>
  </SECTION>
</DOCUMENT>
```

This is my xpath string:

```
//TOKEN [@DOUBLE] [@BEGIN <= ../../SENTENCE[@NAME='PRIMARY']/TOKEN/@END] [ (@SENTENCE_BEGIN = ../../SENTENCE[@NAME='PRIMARY']/TOKEN/@SENTENCE_BEGIN) and (@SENTENCE_END = ../../SENTENCE[@NAME='PRIMARY']/TOKEN/@SENTENCE_END) ]
```

I receive as output two nodes:

```
 <TOKEN BEGIN="17" END="19" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" PROP="C" DOUBLE="YES" />
```

and

```
<TOKEN BEGIN="139" END="141" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" PROP="A" DOUBLE="YES" />
```

The result above is not correct because I want to check that:

1. the `SENTENCE_BEGIN` `SENTENCE_END` values of `TOKEN[@DOULBE=YES]` and 
   `SENTENCE[@NAME="PRIMARY"]/TOKEN` are the same, and
2. the value of the attribute `BEGIN` of `TOKEN[@DOULBE=YES]` is less than the `BEGIN` of `SENTENCE[@NAME="PRIMARY"]/TOKEN`

The result

```
 <TOKEN BEGIN="139" END="141" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" PROP="A" DOUBLE="YES" />
```

is not correct, as the `BEGIN` value **(139)** is greater than the corresponding `BEGIN` values of the tokens with the same `SENTENCE_BEGIN` `SENTENCE_END` values:

```
<TOKEN BEGIN="9" END="11" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" />
<TOKEN BEGIN="32" END="37" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="156" />
```

How can I modify the code line to obtain the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've tagged your question XSLT 1.0, I'd use XSLT instead of pure XPath. That way you can use [xsl:key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#key) and also [current()](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#function-current).

Example...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="primary_tokens" 
    match="SENTENCE[@NAME='PRIMARY']/TOKEN" 
    use="concat(@SENTENCE_BEGIN,'|',@SENTENCE_END)"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:for-each select=".//TOKEN[@DOUBLE='YES'][key('primary_tokens',concat(@SENTENCE_BEGIN,'|',@SENTENCE_END))]">
      <xsl:if test="key('primary_tokens',concat(@SENTENCE_BEGIN,'|',@SENTENCE_END))[@BEGIN > current()/@BEGIN]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiJ8